# User Defined Function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want to convert following in user defined function

```
 wkly = (df.groupby(['Year','Month'], as_index=False).agg(P_HIGH=('High', 'max'),
          D_HIGH=('High', 'idxmax'),
          P_LOW=('Low', 'min'),
          D_LOW=('Low', 'idxmin')))
```

I tried using the def method but the funciton returns none.

Comment: How do you expect us to help without showing the function?

Comment: please attach the code and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to do this, togther with an example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Year': [2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021],
        'Month': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
        'High': [10, 15, 20, 18, 25, 22, 30, 28],
        'Low': [5, 8, 12, 10, 18, 16, 22, 20]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)



def weekly_summary(df):
    weekly = (df.groupby(['Year','Month'], as_index=False).agg(P_HIGH=('High', 'max'),
                                                              D_HIGH=('High', 'idxmax'),
                                                              P_LOW=('Low', 'min'),
                                                              D_LOW=('Low', 'idxmin')))
    return weekly

weekly_summary(df)
```

which returns:

```
   Year  Month  P_HIGH  D_HIGH  P_LOW  D_LOW
0  2020      1      15       1      5      0
1  2020      2      20       2     10      3
2  2021      1      25       4     16      5
3  2021      2      30       6     20      7
```